# Java 8 Stream multiple files flatmap to lines

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Given an array of filenames:

```
bigList = Arrays.stream(files)
    .flatMap(file - > {
        try {
            return Files.lines(Paths.get(path + SEPARATOR + file));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "No se puede encontrar el archivo " + file);
        }
        return null;
    })
    .filter(str - > str.startsWith("ABC"))
    .distinct()
    .map(Mapper::mapToObj)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is returning a different output when I'm using a traditional for loop (instead `Arrays.stream(..).flatMap(..)`)

```
for (String file: files) {
    bigList.addAll(Files.lines(Paths.get(path + SEPARATOR + file))
        .filter(str - > str.startsWith("ABC"))
        .distinct()
        .map(Mapper::mapToObj)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: Sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: @BoristheSpider You were right, I fixed it.

Comment: Is it returning different output, or just the same output in a different order?

Comment: For loop output: List with 79 elements
Stream output: List with 4 elements

Comment: @Boris the Spider: returning `null` in the `flatMap` function has the same effect than returning an empty stream. This has been specified explicitly.

Comment: @delpo: you are counteracting the API. You can use `Paths.get(path, file)` which is there exactly for not having to deal with `SEPARATOR`.

Comment: @Holger I see - I guess that's an RTFM moment. Slightly surprised though.

Comment: @Holger good tip, thanks

Comment: BTW, you are not closing the `Stream<String>` returned by `Files.lines(...)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because  of the call to `distinct()`.

When you call `flatmap`, it combines all lines in all of your files to a single `Stream<String>`, so `distinct()` will return lines which are distinct among all files.

When you use a for loop, you only are calling `distinct()` on the lines in each file individually. So, when you add them to your list, there could still be duplicates if the same line exists in different files.

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, btw thanks for the edit @Andrew Mairose.